# Translate docker run commands with initialization to a multi-container k8s pod or compose

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

I have a container that I need to configure for k8s yaml. The workflow on `docker run` using the terminal looks like this.:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/projects \
             -w /projects \
             gcr.io/base-project/myoh:v1 init *myproject*
```

This command creates a directory called *myproject*. To complete the workflow, I need to cd into this *myproject* folder and run:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/project \
             -w /project \
             -p 8081:8081 \
             gcr.io/base-project/myoh:v1
```

Any idea how to convert this to either a docker-compose or a k8s pods/deployment yaml? I have tried all that come to mind with no success.

Comment: Since there is some confusion in the answers, please clarify whether the bind mount you do to your local machine with $pwd actually expects preexisting files in the mounted directory or whether here the bind mount purely facilitates the sharing of files between containers and could be replaced by a volume mount.

Answer (score 2):

The bind mount of the current directory can't be translated to Kubernetes at all.  There's no way to connect a pod's filesystem back to your local workstation.  A standard Kubernetes setup has a multi-node installation, and if it's possible to directly connect to a node (it may not be) you can't predict which node a pod will run on, and copying code to every node is cumbersome and hard to maintain.  If you're using a hosted Kubernetes installation like GKE, it's even possible that the cluster autoscaler will create and delete nodes automatically, and you won't have an opportunity to manually copy things in.

You need to build your application code into a custom image.  That can set the desired `WORKDIR`, `COPY` the code in, and `RUN` any setup commands that are required.  Then you need to push that to an image repository, like GCR

```
docker build -t gcr.io/base-project/my-project:v1 .
docker push gcr.io/base-project/my-project:v1
```

Once you have that, you can create a minimal Kubernetes [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) to run it.  Set the GCR name of the image you built and pushed as its `image:`.  You will also need a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to make it accessible, even from other Pods in the same cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (untested yaml, but you will get the idea)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myoh-deployment
  labels:
    app: myoh
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myoh
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myoh
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-myoh
        image: gcr.io/base-project/myoh:v1
        command: ['sh', '-c', "mkdir -p myproject"]
      containers:
      - name: myoh
        image: gcr.io/base-project/myoh:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /projects
          name: project-volume
    volumes:
    - name: test-volume
      hostPath:
        # directory location on host
        path: /data
        # this field is optional
        type: Directory
```

Comment: Sameer do you think the `initContainers` changes will be written to the `myoh` container?

Comment: you should attach volumeMount to the `initContainers` as well.

Comment: @Vishrant Yes, initcontainer changes will be visible to main container. and yes, you need to mount volumes in initcontainer if you want to access it there. As I said, this config is untested.